# When using Windows Authentication I can't disable impersonation

Tags: asp.net, iis, impersonation

I have the application pool of a web application set to run as a user called WebUser.

I have the following sections in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

I have created a file called a.txt and given only WebUser permissions on it. If I navigate to this file then I get a 401 error. However if I give my own user account access to this file then I can access it.

So it seems that the application is impersonating my identity. How can I make it run as the application pool user instead?

EDIT: Also - if I enable impersonation and make it impersonate WebUser then I still get a 401 error.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Are you running this in IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012

Comment: When you say "navigate to this file" what do you mean?  Directory browsing?  If so, that's not controlled by asp.net.

Comment: I mean go to http://www.TheSite.com/a.txt

Comment: Ok, but once again, asp.net net doesn't, by default, process txt files

Comment: Are you running integrated or classic mode?  Integrated doesn't support impersonation anyways... so i'm not sure what you think is happening.

Comment: This is in integrated mode. I have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set.

Comment: Well, impersonation is not supported in that mode, so whatever user the app pool is configured to run as is what context the file will be accessed as, unless you have code in the app that does manual impersonation (using a WindowsIdentityContext, for instance).  If you enable impersonation, you should get an error saying it's not supported, which is what has me confused... and makes me think that whatever changes you are making are not to the actual site.

Comment: Ok it is caused by the FileAuthorizationModule. When runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is enabled this will check that the user has access to the file being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved this by going to the site's advanced settings and changing the Physical Path Credential Logon Type to Interactive. I also had to set Physical Path Credentials to Specific User and enter WebUser's credentials, this stopped it from impersonating the authenticated user when accessing files.

Joe